# Arch Linux Setup with Encryption (LVM on LUKS)

Tags: arch-linux, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I'd like to setup Arch Linux with encryption. I found the tutorial on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS), and think that the second option (LVM on LUKS) is the best option for me. Here's the partitioning I'd like to use (Thinkpad X1 Carbon, ~ 500 GB SSD, 16 GB RAM):

0. [alignment gap] 1 MB
1. `/boot` 256 MB (FAT 32)
2. swap 16 GB (size of memory)
3. `/` (root) 64 GB (ext4)
4. `/var` 8 GB (ext4)
5. `/tmp` 4 GB (ext4)
6. `/home` ~400 GB (ext4, remainder)

The disk has the name `nvme0n1`. After booting the installer (September 2020 release) and connecting to the WiFi, I overwrite the disk with random data:

```
# shred --random-source=/dev/urandom --iterations=3 /dev/nvme0n1
```

Then I setup a new GPT partition schema:

```
# parted -s /dev/nvme0n1 mklabel gpt
```

Next, I create and format a boot partition with a 1 MB alignment gap in front of it.

```
# parted -s /dev/nvme0n1 mkpart boot fat32 1MiB 257MiB
# parted -s /dev/nvme0n1 set 1 esp on
# mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Now comes the part, where the wiki is unclear. (It only mentions that it's possible to have `/boot` on a different device, which I don't.) I decided to make another partition, on top of which my encrypted volume will be located:

```
# parted -s /dev/nvme0n1 mkpart cryptlvm 257MiB '100%'
```

This creates a second partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2` with the remainder disk size. (Maybe this step causes the problem.) I continue to setup the encryption:

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p2     # YES, entering passphrase  twice
# cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p2 cryptlvm  # entering passphrase
# pvcreate /dev/mapper/cryptlvm
# vgcreate VolumeGroup /dev/mapper/cryptlvm
```

Then I create the partitions as described above:

```
# lvcreate -L 16G VolumeGroup -n swap
# lvcreate -L 64G VolumeGroup -n root
# lvcreate -L 8G VolumeGroup -n var
# lvcreate -L 4G VolumeGroup -n tmp
# lvcreate -l '100%FREE' VolumeGroup -n home
```

The partitions are now being formatted:

```
# mkswap /dev/VolumeGroup/swap
# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/VolumeGroup/root
# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/VolumeGroup/var
# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/VolumeGroup/tmp
# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/VolumeGroup/home
```

And mounted:

```
# mount /dev/VolumeGroup/root /mnt

# mkdir /mnt/boot
# mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot

# mkdir /mnt/var
mount /dev/VolumeGroup/var /mnt/var

# mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount /dev/VolumeGroup/tmp /mnt/tmp

# mkdir /mnt/home
mount /dev/VolumeGroup/home /mnt/home
```

The system can now be bootstrapped together with `lvm2`:

```
# pacstrap /mnt base liux linux-firmware lvm2
```

I also create and store the `fstab`:

```
# genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

I `chroot` into the bootstrapped system:

```
# arch-chroot /mnt
```

As mentioned in the wiki, I add the hooks `encrypt` and `lvm2` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`:

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect keyboard keymap consolefont modconf block filesystems fsck encrypt lvm2)
```

I continue with the usual setup tasks (setup root password, install base
packages, set timezone, locale, language, hostname):

```
# passwd
# pacman -S iw wpa_supplicant dialog intel-ucode netctl dhcpcd
# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Zurich /etc/localtime
# timedatectl set-ntp true
# hwclock --systohc
# echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen
# locale-gen
# echo 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' > /etc/locale.conf
# echo -n 'x1' > /etc/hostname
```

Now comes the bootloader. Here I traditionally use the systemd bootloader instead of grub. Here's how I set it up:

```
# systemd-machine-id-setup
# bootctl --path=/boot install
```

I figure out the UUID (not PARTUUID) of the root partition as follows:

```
# blkid | grep /dev/VolumeGroup/root | egrep -o 'UUID="[^"]!"'
UUID="6d5b4777-2621-4bec-8bbc-ebd4b5ba9faf"
```

Then I create the boot entry in `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`:

```
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options cryptdevice=UUID=6d5b4777-2621-4bec-8bbc-ebd4b5ba9faf:cryptlvm root/dev/VolumeGroup/root
```

And an accordng `/boot/loader/loader.conf`:

```
default arch
timeout 0
editor  0
```

Last but not least, I run `mkinitcpio`, before leaving for a fresh boot:

```
# mkinitcpio -P
# exit
# umount -R /mnt
# shutdown -h now
```

So that was my setup procedure. I remove the USB dongle and boot the system. The bootloader shows up, but then I get the following screen:

```
:: running early hook [udev]
Starting version 246.6-1-arch
:: running early hook [lvm2]
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
:: running hook [encrypt]
Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/6d5b4777-2621-4bec-8bbc-ebd4b5ba9faf ...
Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/VolumeGroup/root ...
ERROR: device '/dev/VolumeGroup/root' not found. Skippng fsck.
:: mounting '/dev/VolumeGroup/root' on real root
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
```

Now I'm pretty clueless what I've done wrong. One suspicion is the second
partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p2`) that I needed to create. Another suspicion is that
I did something wrong with the bootloader. On regular setups, I always use the
PARTUUID instead of the UUID. (However, there's no PARTUUID in the output of
`blikd`, so this probably isn't the issue.)

Comment: wrong UUID, you specified the rootfs UUID for cryptdevice but it needs the LUKS UUID

Comment: Allow me a comment unrelated to your actual question: I suppose you have good reasons to have separate partitions for `/var` and others. From experience I find your `/var` volume awfully small. I have had to repartition mine on a box very similar to yours to increase over the years from 12GB to 48GB. I repeatedly found myself limited because I tend to use it as an ad-hoc scratch pad when I deal with massive data files. Just a heads up. Of course your mileage **will** vary depending on your use-case.  ;-) Post with great style btw.

Comment: @frostschutz Do you mean the one of `/dev/mapper/cryptlvm` or `/dev/nvme0n1p2`?
EDIT: `/de/nvme0n1p2` is it! Many thanks, I was able to boot my system!

Comment: @Cbhihe Thanks for the remark. I not only thought that people will comment on my partition sizes, but actually hoped for it. I haven't been partitioning my disks properly for long, so I still need some experience. I actually figured out that my `/var` on my work laptop is already 17 GB after nine months. So I think 32 GB or 64 GB might be more appropriate.

Comment: @frostschutz: can you make an answer out of your comment, so the post can be made whole ?

Comment: @frostschutz I'm summarizing the issue in an article/tutorial to be posted later today. I'd like to include that link in my answer.

Comment: One more comment on the size of storage volumes: leaving some free space in your VG (instead of creating an LV using `100%FREE`) allows you to grow an LV when needed, simply typing `lvresize LV -L new_size -r PV`, automatically resizing the contained file system too, even if mounted (while shrinking requires unmounting). The (possible) fragmentation resulting from several `lvresize` would hardly be a relevant issue when using flash memory.

Comment: @fra-san Good idea, I mentioned it in my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @frostschutz hasn't written his correct solution to the problem as an answer yet, I'll summarize the issue here quickly: I picked the UUID of the wrong partition. The root partition under `/dev/VolumeGroup/root` is not the one to be chosen, but the actual partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. Here's how to extract that UUID:

```
# uuid=$(blkid --match-tag UUID -o value /dev/nvme0n1p2)
```

Which then can be used in the boot loader entry config:

```
# cat <<EOF >/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options cryptdevice=UUID=${uuid}:cryptlvm root=/dev/volgrp/root
EOF
```

I summarized the whole procedure on my [private website](https://paedubucher.ch/articles/2020-09-26-arch-linux-setup-with-disk-encryption.html). Thanks also to @Cbhihe for the advice on partition sizes.